# Components of class loading

Tags: java, classloader

I want to know how class loading is done in Java.
Also, I want to know what are the components that are loaded at the time of class loading.

Because I have a class, I am initializing some of the variables in a static way and I need to know if those are initialized properly or not.

Is there any stack trace kind of functionality available to see the components for a class at the time of class loading?

Comment: Try to access the static variables. You'll then know if they are initialized properly.

Comment: Can you please google around a bit regarding Class Loading and gain some knowledge and then come up with some concrete doubts?

Comment: Please post your relevant code along with a clear description of the problem you are encountering, and the steps you have taken to try and resolve it.

Comment: Out of flags, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761377/in-what-order-are-the-different-parts-of-a-class-initialized-when-a-class-is-loa?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how class loading is done in Java.
>   Also, I want to know what are the components that are loaded at the time of class loading.

See:

- [JLS section 12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)
- http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/when-class-loading-initialization-java-example.html, which answers both questions.

> Because I have a class, I am initializing some of the variables in a static way and I need to know if those are initialized properly or not.

See above. In addition, if *you* are not initializing them properly, that is also an issue.

> Is there any stack trace kind of functionality available to see the components for a class at the time of class loading?

You could add `System.out.println()` or other logging output to trace things that you are interested in.